# NextJs routes with param in between routes

Tags: next.js

Is there a way in nextjs to create routes like `/services/${service.id}/subscriptions`?

I have many subroutes where the serviceId is needed. My initial fould would be to create a folder structure like so but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

[image]

Edit: using page router

Comment: we should start mentioning pages / app router  ...

Comment: @KcH Absolutely!

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen inside the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#example) you have accidentally created a [catch-all segment](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments) while what you are searching for is a simple [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#example). Here is an example

```js
interface Props {
  params: { serviceId: string },
}

// app/services/[serviceId]/subscriptions/page.tsx
export default async function Page(props: Props): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const { serviceId } = props.params;

  const response = await fetch(`https://example.com/services/${serviceId}`);
  const json = await response.json();

  return (
    <pre>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)}</code>
    </pre>
  );
}
```

Please note that stack overflow expects you to do a [certain degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593) yourself before posting a question, this answer is curated information from the official documentation, ultimately easily accessible via a simple google search.